# how to copy folders from my linux machine to a docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 
RUN apt-get update
WORKDIR /home/
RUN mkdir folder1
COPY /home/folder1/* /home/folder1
RUN mkdir folder2
COPY /home/folder2/* /home/folder2
```

I have written the above to copy 2 folders from my pc to a docker container using this dockerfile. I am giving the correct path of folders from source. Dockerfile and folders to be copied and Dockerfile are present on the same level
but I am getting this error

```
=> ERROR [5/7] COPY /home/folder1/* /home/folder1                       0.0s 
------                                                                          
 > [5/7] COPY /home/sushant/jetson/* ./jetson:                                  
------                                                                          
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |     WORKDIR /home/
   5 |     RUN mkdir jetson
   6 | >>> COPY /home/folder1/* /home/folder1
   7 |     RUN mkdir cuda
   8 |     COPY /home/folder2/* /home/folder2
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2125610381/home/folder1: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left-hand side of a `COPY` directive is always relative to the *build context*, the directory you passed as the argument to `docker build` or named in a `docker-compose.yml` file.  For example, if you do the very common

```bash
docker build .
```

then even though they look like absolute paths, the `/home/folder1` on the left-hand side is actually interpreted as relative to the current directory `.`.

In another answer you note that the `Dockerfile`, `folder1`, and `folder2` are all in the same directory, again a typical setup.  In this case you need to use a relative path on the left-hand side of `COPY`

```bash
FROM ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR /home
COPY ./folder1/* /home/folder1/
COPY ./folder2/* /home/folder2/
```

I tend to also use a relative path (relative to `WORKDIR`) on the right-hand side of `COPY` as well.  `COPY` creates the destination directory if needed and so you do not need to `RUN mkdir`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to copy should be in the same directory where your Dockerfile is located.
Move folder1 and folder2 to the directory where your Dockerfile is located then build the image again.

Comment: yes both folder and Dockerfile are in the same directory still getting this error..

Comment: @SushantSingh your Dockerfile and folders are inside the home directory. For convenience could you move them into a folder and specify COPY ./folder1/* /home/folder1 (Notice adding a dot "." to specify the current working directory)

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) function.

By using the following command:
`docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH LOCAL_DEST_PATH`
or
`docker cp [OPTIONS] LOCAL_SRC_PATH CONTAINER:DEST_PATH`

You should be able to achieve what's needed. You can refer to the docker documentation regarding the command at any time.

Good Luck!

Comment: Please don't post answers that solely link to external documentation

Comment: Understandable @NicoHaase i've adjusted the answer to reflect the documentations contents.